# IronWebScraper in ASP.NET C# WebAPI not calling Parse

Tags: c#, web-scraping

So all the example code on IronWebScraper is a Console Application and it worked well but I'm tried to use it in ASP.NET API, the code never reaches the Parse method in HelloScrapper class:

```
public class ScrapAPIController : ApiController
{     
    [HttpPost, HttpOptions]
    public dynamic ScrapTest()
    {
        try
        {               
            var scraper = new HelloScraper();
            scraper.Start();
            return new {
                code = 1,
                msg = "OK"
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log handler
        }
        return new
        {
            code = -1,
            msg = "Error"
        };
    }
}


public class HelloScraper : WebScraper
{             
    public override void Init()
    {       
        this.LoggingLevel = WebScraper.LogLevel.All; // All Events Are Logged
        this.Request("https://somewebsite.com", Parse);
    }
     
    public override void Parse(Response response)
    {
        // unreachable code
    }        
}
```

What am I missing here?

I tried to call

```
var scraper = new HelloScraper();

scraper.Start();
```

in Global.asax

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
      
        var scraper = new HelloScraper();
        scraper.Start();
    }
}
```

and it turns out working fine when I do that, but still don't have any clue why it's not working in API Controller

Comment: You're not calling the `parse` method in the code you have posted.

Comment: oops, sorry I made a mistake when posting the code. I actually did call Parse in `this.Request()`.

Comment: If I read you correctly, this all works fine when you initialize the scraper in `Application_Start`.  Controllers are what I would call *ephemeral;* once the controller request completes, any variables you declared there go out of scope and are therefore gone.  Your code in `Application_Start` doesn't look particularly kosher to me either, since you're holding a local copy of the variable and not a global instance of it.

Comment: In other words, requests to ASP.NET MVC controllers are *transitory;* they're not meant to be long-running.  It might work for awhile if you put a field in your controller class that holds your `Scrape` method, but controllers are not really designed to work this way.

Comment: Appreciate your patience as my presentation is unclear. What I mean is when I tried to initialize an `HelloScraper` object in `Application_Start` for my demo app, the code still runs through `Parse` method. However, when I move the initialize to an API (because I need the user can pass some parameters to the `Parse` method each time they call the API) it never reaches the `Parse` method as my question.

Comment: I still think it's a scoping problem.  If `Start()` is not a blocking method, as its name suggests, then your scraper evaporates as soon as you `return`.